# Calculating risk for a density estimator

Tags: estimation, density-function, risk

I am trying to solve a textbook problem in Wasserman's "All of Nonparametric Statistics." I have run into a lot of messy integration and am confident that the crowdsource can show me what I am missing.

The problem comes up in calculating the risk for estimators. We obtain an IID sample $X_1, X_2, \dots , X_n \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\theta,1)$. We wish to use the data to estimate the density. Let $\hat\theta = \bar X_n$ and $\hat f(x) = f_{\hat\theta}(x)$. That is, simply consider the normal density whose mean is the sample mean. What is the risk of $\hat f$?

I tried doing $E[L(\hat f(x), f(x))] = E[f(x)^2 -2\hat f(x) f(x) +\hat f(x)^2]$. But this expectation is not so simple as we need to integrate with respect to a bunch of normal densities? Is this the right approach?

Comment: How exactly is the loss function defined?

Comment: Assume square loss: $L(\hat f(x), f(x)) = (\hat f(x) - f(x))^2$

Comment: Unless $x$ is a single number, that's not a loss function!

Comment: Correct, $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Then please explain what $x$ represents.  How is it related to your sample of $n$ values?  There is some kind of disconnect between the parts of your question: if you view $\hat f$ as an estimator of a PDF, then your subsequent expressions for risk make no sense.  The risk is the expected loss which in turn is a function of $\theta$ and $\hat \theta$.

Comment: $x$ is simply a point at which a density estimator is being assessed in terms of expected loss. The density estimator itself $\hat{f}(x)$ is a function of the data. So in this case $\theta=f(x)$ and $\hat\theta = \hat f(x)$.

Comment: To clarify, the expectation is wrt to the RVs that make up $\hat f(x)$ not $x$ itself. We are trying to trying to figure out risk as a function of $x$.

Comment: The problem is that $\hat f$ is a function of the *entire sample*, not of each $X_i$ individually.  Your expression for the loss just doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Again, the purpose of this question is to clarify what the book is asking for. Perhaps it is simply a poorly worded question. I believe it is asking for an expectation over all the $X_i$'s so $n$ integrals. The quiz that I was hoping to clarify this for has passed -- perhaps I should just move on.